# ¿Cómo guardar una imagen con PHP en el servidor pero a partir de una imagen almacenada en mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, imagen

he intentado con move_uploaded_file y el $_file pero segun he leido solo es para cargar imagenes desde el cliente y lo que quiero es pasar la imagen desde la base de datows mysql a una carpeta del servidoR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se debe hacer con `file_put_contents`, para escribir datos en un archivo (si no existe lo crea).

> [file_put_contents](http://file_put_contents%20%E2%80%94%20Escribir%20datos%20en%20un%20fichero%20%20Descripci%C3%B3n%20%C2%B6%20file_put_contents(%20%20%20%20%20string%20$filename,%20%20%20%20%20mixed%20$data,%20%20%20%20%20int%20$flags%20=%200,%20%20%20%20%20resource%20$context%20=%20?%20):%20int%20Esta%20funci%C3%B3n%20es%20id%C3%A9ntica%20que%20llamar%20a%20fopen(),%20fwrite()%20y%20fclose()%20sucesivamente%20para%20escribir%20informaci%C3%B3n%20en%20un%20fichero.%20%20Si%20filename%20no%20existe,%20se%20crea%20el%20fichero.%20De%20otro%20modo,%20el%20fichero%20existente%20se%20sobrescribe,%20a%20menos%20que%20la%20bandera%20FILE_APPEND%20est%C3%A9%20establecida.) — Escribir datos en un fichero
>
> Descripción :
>
> ```
> file_put_contents(
>     string $filename,
>     mixed $data,
>     int $flags = 0,
>     resource $context = ?
> ): int
> ```
>
> > Esta función es idéntica que llamar a fopen(), fwrite() y fclose()
> > sucesivamente para escribir información en un fichero.
> >
> > Si filename no existe, se crea el fichero. De otro modo, el fichero
> > existente se sobrescribe, a menos que la bandera FILE_APPEND esté
> > establecida.

Comment: guao sos un genio muchisimas gracias me a funcionado a la perfección